# how to view all location quantities

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys this is the entire file.

```
<tbody id="cart_contents">
  <?php
  if(count($cart)==0)
  {?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='8'>
            <div class='warning_message' style='padding: 7px;'><?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_no_items_in_cart'); ?></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } else {               
      $tabindex = 2;              
      foreach(array_reverse($cart, true) as $line=>$item)
      {                   
          if($tabindex == 3) {
              $tabindex = 5;
          }                   
          echo form_open("sales/edit_item/$line");?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo anchor("sales/delete_item/$line",'['.$this->lang->line('common_delete').']');?></td>
              <td><?php echo $item['item_number']; ?></td>
              <td style="align: center;"><?php echo base64_decode($item['name']); ?><br /> [<?php echo $item['in_stock'] ?> in <?php echo $item['stock_name']; ?>]
                  <?php echo form_hidden('location', $item['item_location']); ?>
              </td>
              <?php 
                            if ($items_module_allowed)
              {?>
                  <td><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6'));?></td>
              <?php } else {?>
                  <td><?php echo to_currency($item['price']); ?></td>
                  <?php echo form_hidden('price',$item['price']); ?>
              <?php }?>
              <td>
              <?php
              if($item['is_serialized']==1) {
                  echo $item['quantity'];
                  echo form_hidden('quantity',$item['quantity']);
              } else {                               
                  echo form_input(array('name'=>'quantity','value'=>$item['quantity'],'size'=>'2','tabindex'=>$tabindex));
              }?>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'discount','value'=>$item['discount'],'size'=>'3'));?></td>
              <td><?php echo to_currency($item['price']*$item['quantity']-$item['price']*$item['quantity']*$item['discount']/100); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo form_submit("edit_item", $this->lang->line('sales_edit_item'));?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <?php 
              if($item['allow_alt_description']==1)
              {?>
                  <td style="color: #2F4F4F;"><?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_description_abbrv').':';?></td>
              <?php }?>
              <td colspan=2 style="text-align: left;">
              <?php
              if($item['allow_alt_description']==1)
              {
                  echo form_input(array('name'=>'description','value'=>base64_decode($item['description']),'size'=>'20'));
              }
              else
              {
                  if (base64_decode($item['description'])!='')
                  {
                      echo base64_decode($item['description']);
                      echo form_hidden('description',base64_decode($item['description']));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      echo $this->lang->line('sales_no_description');
                      echo form_hidden('description','');
                  }
              }
              ?>
              </td>
              <td>
              <!-- printing custom fields here -->
              </td>
              <td style="color: #2F4F4F;">
              <?php
              if($item['is_serialized']==1)
              {
                  echo $this->lang->line('sales_serial').':';
              }
              ?>
              </td>
              <td colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
              <?php
              if($item['is_serialized']==1)
              {
                  echo form_input(array('name'=>'serialnumber','value'=>$item['serialnumber'],'size'=>'20'));
              }
              else
              {
                  echo form_hidden('serialnumber', '');
              }
              ?>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="height: 3px">
              <td colspan=8 style="background-color: white"></td>
          </tr>
          </form>
                <?php                   
          $tabindex = $tabindex + 1;                  
      }
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

what i want is all location quantity be visible under item name, it only displays the selected quantity of selected location, all i want it that text field to display all locations here is on example [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ct6c.jpg)

as you can see is separated i will like it to have all info of location independently of what location is selected when searching for items.

this is codeigniter I'm trying for days now but I'm a new with php and this framework, I will really appreciate this help